# Insert from multiple select MS Access 2013 C# Error

Tags: c#, ms-access-2013

I've got an error in query I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Manuacturer_Item (item_id, manufacturer_id) 
SELECT      i.id, 
            m.id 
FROM        Item AS i 
CROSS JOIN  Manufacturer AS m 
WHERE       i.iname LIKE 'PC' AND m.mname LIKE'zaz'
```

What have I missed?

Comment: What is the detailed error message?

Comment: It's a syntax error, I tried this query in MS SQL Server, It works, but Access is not

Comment: Syntax error near FROM it's the message

Comment: Yes I tried, message is Syntax error near INSERT INTO

Comment: What is your `SELECT  i.id, m.id FROM Item AS i CROSS JOIN Manufacturer AS m WHERE   i.iname like 'PC' AND     m.mname like 'zaz'` returns exactly?

Comment: i've got 3 tables Item with id Manufacturer with id and Manuacturer_Item with item_id and manufacturer_id I would like SELECT id from Item and Manufacturet and INSERT it into Manuacturer_Item

Comment: Improved formatting and grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Access SQL it could be:

```
INSERT INTO Manuacturer_Item 
    (item_id, manufacturer_id) 
SELECT  
    i.id, m.id 
FROM 
    [Item] AS i,
    Manufacturer AS m 
WHERE   
    i.iname like 'PC' AND m.mname like 'zaz'
```